# figure disappears if \linewidth set too large

Tags: subcaption

I have one other figure before this one that displays just fine. But if I set the size of the subfigures to a width any greater than .5\linewidth, the figures disappear. Can anyone help?

```
\setcounter{figure}{1}
\captionsetup[subcaption]{labelformat=default}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=default}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{2a.png}
        \caption{cap 1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vspace{1cm}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth, angle=-90]{2b.pdf}
        \caption{cap 2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Figure Cap}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: Welcome to [TSE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). Please add a minimal working example.

Comment: Probably setting right argument of `\begin{subfigure}[t]{\linewidth}` will solve the problem. e.g. `\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\linewidth}` for both subfigures and remove `width=.5\linewidth` from `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Please clarify what "disappears" entails. Does the figure vanish entirely, or does it get placed at the very end of the document?

Comment: `\begin{figure}[ht]` is preventing the figure being placed on a page of figures so if the two subfigures make it too large to fit on a text page it will have no legal place and so you are forcing it to the end of the document (unless flushed with `\clearpage`)